# Conways game of life

Tags: java

> Create a method called live that accepts a row and column, then returns a boolean that determines if an existing cell in that location will live or die (or a cell will be created) according to a set of rules (Conway’s game of Life).  When checking the number of cells around a cell, be careful to consider the boundaries of the array.

I already have the method but I don't know what to do inside that method.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;  // Needed for ActionListener
import javax.swing.event.*;  // Needed for ActionListener

class LifeSimulationGUIDemo extends JFrame
{
    static Colony colony = new Colony (0.5);
    static Timer t;

    //======================================================== constructor
    public LifeSimulationGUIDemo ()
    {
        // 1... Create/initialize components
        BtnListener btnListener = new BtnListener (); // listener for all buttons

        JButton simulateBtn = new JButton ("Simulate");
        simulateBtn.addActionListener (btnListener);

        // 2... Create content pane, set layout
        JPanel content = new JPanel ();        // Create a content pane
        content.setLayout (new BorderLayout ()); // Use BorderLayout for panel
        JPanel north = new JPanel ();
        north.setLayout (new FlowLayout ()); // Use FlowLayout for input area

        DrawArea board = new DrawArea (500, 500);

        // 3... Add the components to the input area.

        north.add (simulateBtn);

        content.add (north, "North"); // Input area
        content.add (board, "South"); // Output area

        // 4... Set this window's attributes.
        setContentPane (content);
        pack ();
        setTitle ("Life Simulation");
        setSize (510, 570);
        setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo (null);           // Center window.
    }

    class BtnListener implements ActionListener 
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getActionCommand ().equals ("Simulate"))
            {
                Movement moveColony = new Movement (); // ActionListener for timer
                t = new Timer (200, moveColony); // set up Movement to run every 200 milliseconds
                t.start (); // start simulation
            }
            repaint ();            // refresh display of colony
        }
    }

    class DrawArea extends JPanel
    {
        public DrawArea (int width, int height)
        {
            this.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (width, height)); // size
        }

        public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
        {
            colony.show (g); // display current state of colony
        }
    }

    class Movement implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {
            colony.advance (); // advance to the next time step
            repaint (); // refresh 
        }
    }

    //======================================================== method main
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        LifeSimulationGUIDemo window = new LifeSimulationGUIDemo ();
        window.setVisible (true);
    }
}

class Colony
{


    private boolean grid[] [];

    public  boolean live ( int row, int column)
    {


    }



    public Colony (double density)
    {
        grid = new boolean [100] [100];
        for (int row = 0 ; row < grid.length ; row++)
            for (int col = 0 ; col < grid [0].length ; col++)
                grid [row] [col] = Math.random () < density;
    }

    public void show (Graphics g)
    {
        for (int row = 0 ; row < grid.length ; row++)
            for (int col = 0 ; col < grid [0].length ; col++)
            {
                if (grid [row] [col]) // life
                    g.setColor (Color.black);
                else
                    g.setColor (Color.white);
                g.fillRect (col * 5 + 2, row * 5 + 2, 5, 5); // draw life form
            }
    }

    public void advance ()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We're not a coding service. You should at least _try_ to solve your task by yourself. Come back to ask when you got stuck on a specific problem.

Comment: thanks ill try to solve the problem before asking

Comment: Exactly as @RenéVogt says. I'm glad that you've got an answer, but many if not most of us will wait, and not give an answer until you at least show your best good faith effort to solve this. Otherwise the question is little more than a homework dump.

Comment: I understand what your saying, dont worry this wont happen again

Answer (score 3):

If you're not familiar with Conway's Game of Life, a quick introduction might be necessary:

The **Game of Life** is a cellular automaton devised by John Conway back in 1970. **Life**, for short, is essentially a simulation of the simple dynamics of life itself --- birth, reproduction, and death. With a given seed or initial input, Life will play out by itself and, based on the core rules you are seeking help on, will decide what cells live, reproduce, or die.

Check out the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life#Rules) for the rules on Conway's Game of Life:

> - Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if caused by under-population.
> - Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.
> - Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by over-population.
> - Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.

Essentially, your `live()` method will implement those core rules to decide whether or not the cell at the given row and column will live.

The easiest way I can think of to provide an example would be with a set of `if`/`else` statements:

```
public boolean live (int row, int column)
{
     // If the cell we're checking is currently alive
     if (grid[row][col]) // This is equal to: "if (grid[row][col] == true)"
     {
         // Check if fewer than two live neighbors exist
         if (neighborCheck(row, column) < 2)
         {
              // Cell dies due to under-population.
              return false;
         }   
         // Check if two or three live neighbors exist
         if (neighborCheck(row, column) <= 3)
         {
              // Cell lives.
              return true;
         }
         // Check if more than three live neighbors exist
         if (neighborCheck(row, column) > 3)
         {
              // Cell dies due to over-population.
              return false;
         }
     }
     // If the cell we're checking is currently dead
     else
     {
         // Check if cell has exactly three neighbors
         if (neighborCheck(row, column) == 3)
         {
              // Cell becomes alive.
              return true;
         }
     }
}
```

In the code above, I've written `live()` to be based directly off of the rules above. The code first checks the cell at the given row and column (`grid[row][column]`) for life. If it is living (if `grid[row][column] == true`), the code then checks if the cell will continue to live or die. If the cell is dead (`false`), then the code will skip to the `else` block.

In each check, I've written a neighborCheck() call. That's a method (that hasn't been written yet) that will check each of the **8 neighbors** surrounding the given cell and return the number of living neighbors.

This image: (http://abyss.uoregon.edu/~js/images/life_rules.gif) illustrates the relationship between the cell and its neighbors quite well. And here's a template to follow for the `neighborCheck()` method:

```
private int neighborCheck(int row, int column)
{ 
    // Iterate through each neighbor, count the living ones, and return it
    ...add your code here.
}
```

To iterate through each neighbor, you'll need to mathematically calculate where each cell is in relation to the current cell. I'll let you write the code for that, but just remember that you're working in two dimensions. For example, the **top-left** neighbor would be **minus one** in row number and **minus one** in column number to the current cell (`grid[row - 1][column - 1]`, **top-middle** neighbor would be **minus one** in row number but **unchanged** in column number (`grid[row - 1][column]`), etc.

Comment: thanks and next for sure ill try first before asking for help